# Does the limit of the sequence $a(n) = \frac{n^2+7}{n^3+5}$, and its partial sum exist?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

We are given that $a(n) = \frac{n^2+7}{n^3+5}$ and $s(n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a(n)$ is the corresponding partial sum.

How can I determine the existence of the limit as n approaches infinity of $s(n)$ without actually determining the value of the limit?

I have been told that I could use the comparison test but I don't know how to. Is there any other way or test that I can use?

Comment: Does it help, along with your hint, that $n a(n)\to 1$?

Comment: Note $\displaystyle{n^2+7\over n^3+5}\ge{n^2\over n^3+5}\ge {n^2\over n^3+n^3}={1\over 2n}$ for $n\ge2$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

Comparison Criterion for positive series plus

$$\frac{n^2+7}{n^3+5}\ge\frac{n^2}{2n^3}=\frac12\cdot\frac1n$$

Last hint: Harmonic Series.